# How to print large OSM basemap in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, print-composer, basemap

I am very new to QGIS, and an active OpenStreetMap contributor. I would like to print a map to hang on my wall to help me coordinate mapping activities in my town.

I have access to a printer that can print Arch D (24"x36"). I would like to make a map that is approximately 48"x72". I plan on cutting by hand the edges of the printed maps that I'll tape together, since the printer doesn't print well on margins (which means I will have 0.5" margins). I figure that I can split the map up into four sections. I managed to get access to the OSM basemap via some API.

I created a print layout with four pages and four added map items, but I am stuck on trying to get the size, position, extents and margins correct. Everytime I change the extents, the size and position changes, and everytime I change the size and position, the extents changes. The QGIS documentation wasn't that helpful and I wasn't able to find a tutorial/post that targets this activity. I can attach my working files, layouts, and libreoffice sheet if that would help.

Bonus: I am using a libreoffice calc sheet to calculate the midpoints for the map extents that I am manually inputting by hand into the print layout extents for each map. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Hi IvanVG, welcome to GIS SE. Do you know the atlas function? Creating a layer with 4 polygons, representing the areas you want to print, should do the job. See: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/overview_composer.html#atlas-menu and https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html